# Java string tokenizer delimiter

Tags: java, string, delimiter

I have a string `"domain\cdsid"`, where `"\"` is the delimiter, all I want is to split the string and just print `"cdsid"`.

Input string : `"domain\cdsid"`

Output string : `"cdsid"`

How do I do this ?

Comment: Whay have you tried? Split the string by delimiter and access the resulting array

Answer (score 1):

Try this (using `split`) :

```
String myText = "domain\\cdsid";
System.out.println(myText.split("\\\\")[1]);
```

Output :

```
cdsid
```

Comment: That looks fine, but if you see this here.                                             "String[]  loginname= 
(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("LoginName").getNodeValue()).split("\\");"              Iam extracting the data from sharepoint and its the "LoginName" which has this format "domain\cdsid" its predefined.

Comment: You can't have a ``\`` inside a String, so, even if the method is returning the string `"domain\cdsid"`, it actually IS `"domain\\cdsid"`, and hence, the corresponding split.

Comment: Glad you got it. Please mark the answer as accepted. :) @IrthizaKhan

Answer (score 0):

In Java String object "\" is used to define any escape sequence character like \n for new line, \t for tab, \\ for having a backslash in the String object.

So instead of writing String object as

> String str = "domain\cdsid";

You have to write

> String str = "domain\\cdsid";

The first option will give compile time error. Java will expect that after backslash their must be some escape sequence character but it is not their in first case. It will compile time error as

> Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )

In the above compile time error each separate value is a escape sequence character in java.

So your final code will be

```
String str = "domain\\cdsid";
System.out.println(str.split("\\\\")[1]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you even ran the code before posting the solution ?

Comment: Sorry but which part is giving the error ? I already mentioned that first option will give compile time error in the explanation.

Comment: The `"final"` code you posted.

Comment: I edited the answer. Thank you Jarvis for letting me know.

Comment: Understand what you were saying. Edited the answer.

Answer (score -1):

**Splitting** is a way that I will recommended to go when you need all the elements resulting of the operation... this is because the result will generate an Array of Strings (what a waste of memory generating an array to only get ONE element! :) dont you think??)

in your case something like **regex** or just **substrings** will gently provide you the correct answer..

consider:

```
String txt = "domain\\cdsid";
System.out.println(txt.substring(txt.indexOf("\\") + 1));
```

output:

> **cdsid**